# Are sockets the only option when it comes for my server to see some data to my iPhone?

Tags: ios, sockets

Is there any other way for the server to send data to it's client? Of course that the client could poll the server each 3 seconds to check for updates, but this is not scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your app is in the foreground then the options are:
- the server sends an Apple Push Notification to the device, as your app is in the foreground the OS will deliver the APN to your app uses it as a indication that the server has new data for the client.
- you poll
- you use a technique like, or a varient, of Comet.(basically keep a connection active which the server pings when it has data)

If your app has moved to the background and you are not suspended (you have registered a task via beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: or you are a valid background app) the options are the same except the APN would be displayed to the user and not interceptable by the app.

If you app has moved to the background and is suspended you have no options (apart from APN, but the user will see it).

Answer (score 1):

You can use apple push notification, long polling and websockets, these are the alternatives. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596368/long-polling-vs-apple-push-notification-service-android-c2dm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501121/websockets-client-for-objective-c-preferrably-ios-compatible).