# Is there any cordova plugin for pushnotification without using GCM and APN?

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on android project where i have to show push notification but without using the GCM(Google Cloud Messeging) used for android and APN (Apple Push Notification) for apple.. So is there any other way to do so.?

Comment: There are alternative ways to achieve this, but why you need this?

Comment: m developing an app for event management.. so will b checking continiously for every moment..from data base that is there any event at current time.. so for this purpose i need to show notification.

Comment: My question was: why you need a custom push service instead of GCM and APN?

Comment: No, you can't, apple push needs APN and google push need GCM. You can use some services that make it transparent for you, but they will use GCM and APN

Comment: possible duplicate of [Long-polling vs Apple Push Notification Service & Android C2DM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596368/long-polling-vs-apple-push-notification-service-android-c2dm)

Comment: because i am not aware about how this GCM & APN works.. I read about it that it needs some project number from developer console. So i am not completely aware of how it works and how to implement using it..